# React native update state change in global variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created 1 component which has 1 button and 1 text.I have created a js file called global.js which stores the device_type. Now when I press the button I called a function which is created on different file. This function update the global variable device_type to Android or IOS. When there is change in the global variable, It should reflect in my component screen and update the Text field. How can I achieve it?

Let me explain in detail.
First I created component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Keyboard } from 'react-native'
import checkDevice from './CheckDevice'
import globals from './globals'

//Componet screen which will display on device
const checkDeviceType = () =>{
    const [deviceType,setDeviceType] = useState(globals.devive_type)

useEffect ( ()=>{
}[deviceType])
    return(
        <View>
<Button title = 'Save Post' onPress = {()=> checkDevice.checkType()}/>
<Text> {dviceType} </Text>
</View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

})

export default EditScreen

//Function to check deviceType create in separate file
import globals from './globals'
const checkDevice = {
checkType = () =>{
  call method to get device type
  globals.devive_type = 'Android' 
}
```

Now when I click on button the text

For now Im using call back functions. But I thinks its not the right way

Comment: deepak , by using callback functions its working right? there's no harm in callback functions.

Comment: Yes but onClick I call function which call another function.So I have to pass callback parameter call to every calling function

Comment: yeah so what's the problem there? that's the way react suggests to pass a callback function

Comment: Interesting thought, but what I understand from the question, the issue is you aren't really making the component re-render. It does change the global variable using the button click. But to see the effect you need to make the rerender the component. If you want to keep a global state without using huge libraries,  take a look at `https://github.com/andregardi/use-global-hook` just few lines of code, just react 16 useState and useEffect, would do the trick for you.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu You are right. The  component does not re-render  since the global variable is declared in other file.And as per the code there is no way we know the device_type variable changed and we need to call setDeviceType function.

Answer (score 0):

If the global variable is defined in any parent component of your component (containing button and text field) you shall be able to access it as props in you component.

Can you please share your code like this it is very confusing.
Write to me if you have any more doubt.
Hopefully, this is helpful.
Thanks